# Attempting to Index through an Array of X & Y values for D3 Drag

Tags: javascript, json, indexing, d3.js

Hi I am currently calling a set of json data using the built D3 request for Json. The current problem I am having is trying to index through my array of data within that request. At the moment I am only able to get the first x & y of my array. It therefore affects my D3 drag as each time I drag a new object it jumps back to the previous position of where the mouse was clicked. Here's a snippet:

```
     d3.json("url/path", function(data) {



        var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
             .origin(Object)
             .on("drag", function(d,i) {
             data.locations[0].x += d3.event.dx;
             data.locations[0].y += d3.event.dy;
   d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate("+data.locations[0].x+","+data.locations[0].y+")")

 });

    .attr("transform", function(d,i) {return  "translate("+data.locations[0].x+","+data.locations[0].y+")" ;})

             });
```

However if I attempt to index through the whole data of locations e.g.

```
        "translate("+data[i].locations[0].x+","+data[i].locations[0].y+")"
```

I receive an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'locations' of undefined "

My current json data is structured like so:

```
        {
 "section":"a",
 "room":"b",
 "locations":[
  {
     "x":0,
     "y":0
  },
  {
     "x":0,
     "y":0
  },
  {
     "x":0,
     "y":0
  },
  {
     "x":0,
     "y":0
  },
  {
     "x":0,
     "y":0
  },
  {
     "x":0,
     "y":0
  }
  ]
 }
```

So my query is how do I index through my nested data, so it reads ALL of the x & y values rather than just one & affect my drag behavior.

Help would be much appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. Pretty Simple! Don't know why I didnt think of it before!

```
 "translate("+data.locations[i].x+","+data.locations[i].y+")"\
```

I believe that is it. if anyone has another solution I'm open to listen.